Prisoners required to dig their own graves and then beheaded in the woods
In the late nineties, I was still a kid, I watched somewhere a VHS movie. Particularly there was a scene that impacted me and I might remember something about it.
There were some kind of soldiers who held prisoners in the woods. Those were obliged to dig their own graves in a row. After that they were kneeling before their grave and they were beheaded and thrown to the graves. 
That's all I can remember, it could be different though. It could be Vietnam, or in the World War II in Japan or somewhere.

Possibly The Highest Honor from 1982. It's about Australian WWII POWs in Singapore and ends with them executed in the way you've described (kneeling near open graves and decapitation). The relevant scene appears in its trailer around 2:15.
